# Сборка nginx с openssl

Tags: nginx, debian, сборка, openssl, makefile

Здравствуйте. Имеется `nginx 12.2.2` и `openssl-1.1.0g`. Сервак: `Linux debian 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Собираю `nginx` из исходных файлов и столкнулся с проблемой на этапе `checkinstall make`:

```
Makefile:261: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «install_dev»
make[2]: *** [install_dev] Ошибка 1
make[2]: выход из каталога «/root/down/openssl-1.1.0g»
objs/Makefile:1588: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «/root/down/openssl-1.1.0g/.openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h»
make[1]: *** [/root/down/openssl-1.1.0g/.openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h] Ошибка 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/root/down/nginx-1.12.2»
Makefile:8: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «build»
make: *** [build] Ошибка 2
```

Грешил на версию `nginx` и взял более свежую - `nginx-1.13.9`, реакция такая же.
Попробовал другую версию `openssl`: `openssl-1.0.2n` - всё собралось, всё работает.
Но возникает закономерный вопрос, а что было не так с той версией?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Связка `make && checkinstall make isntall` всё устанавливает, видимо баги пакета `checkinstall`